# External Access to PieCloudDB Database

Tags: jdbc, dbeaver

I encountered errors when trying to connect to virtual data warehouse in PieCloudDB database using JDBC or DBeaver client tools. How can I configure the permissions to enable external access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked PieCloudDB's doc, JDBC is supported. You can try to find the coordinator information for the corresponding virtual data warehouse, including the installation directory and server port. You should also check the access ACL (Access Control List) information in the pg_hba.conf file and enable external access permissions.

```
ps -ef|grep dispatch  ###check coordinator service port
cd /home/openpie/cn0/mytest/1/6003/ ###adjust the specific paths according to your actual deployment situation.
vim pg_hba.conf ###Add the following content after the "IPv4 local connections:"
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

[image]

Then execute the following command to apply the configuration:

```
ps -ef|grep dispatch    ###check the PID of the coordinator process.
kill -SIGHUP pid
```

[image]